# Is set $[0,1)$ compact in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, compactness

I know that $[0,1]$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ using nested interval theorem. But I am stuck for the case of $[0,1)$. How to do this?

Comment: Compact ALWAYS implies closed and bounded. Therefore, if an interval is not closed... Although you should mention if you're using some wacky topology where open and closed sets mean something different from the usual.

Comment: It's not hard to cook up an "expanding" open cover that can't possibly reduce finitely (just creep toward $1$).  This avoids Heine Borel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Heine-Borel Theorem characterizes compact sets in $\mathbb{R}$: a set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. But this is not the case.

*Note:* more generally, this is true for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 3):

You can check that

$$[0,1)\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$$
where
$$A_1 = (-\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2})$$
$$A_n = (0,1-\frac{1}{n})\text{ for } n\geq 2$$

is an open cover for $[0,1)$. But you can't cover $[0,1)$ with only finitely many of these covering sets.

To see why you can't cover $[0,1)$ with only finitely many of them, suppose that we have chosen the covering sets indexed by $n_1,\cdots,n_k$ to cover $[0,1)$. Set $m=\max(n_1,\cdots,n_k)$. Then any number $\frac{m-1}{m} \leq x < 1$ will not be covered by $A_{n_1},\cdots,A_{n_k}$ which shows that a finite subcover does not exist and $[0,1)$ is not compact.

Comment: Well, let $\epsilon =2$....

Comment: @Randall OK, OK. :P Bad notation. I fixed it. xD Nice to meet you again by the way.

Comment: I don't see the point $\frac 1 2 \in [0,1)$ in your open cover

Comment: Ok, you changed it, so now I do ;-)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, I changed it but it wasn't good. So, I changed it again and now it's good. :D Thank you for pointing it out. xD

Comment: I suppose you mean the covering sets $A_{n_1}, \ldots , A_{n_k}$, i.e., the covering sets indexed by $n_1, \ldots, n_k$

Comment: @stressedout:  I hope my comment didn't make you more stressed out